# buttons to display accordian content in fixed footer format

Tags: html, css, button, footer

I want to create "buttons" in the footer. These buttons when clicked will reveal content in an accordian type style. I have generated the coded that I think is perfect, and it works, however, when I click on one, all of the buttons move upwards with the content. I would only like one to move up, and the rest to stay locked on the footer. Also, possibly centering within the window (currently its sticking to the left)

Any help would be appreciated.

I added in an image to show what I am wanting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1BxQ.png)

And now the code is below:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0px;
   margin-left: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
   width:100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;

}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.accordion {
  padding: 18px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  text-align: left;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel p {
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My footer buttons</h2>
<div class="footer">
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">

  <div class="div1">
   <button class="accordion">Button 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
  <p>Button 1 content and information to go here <br><br><a href="">more information</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  <div class="column">


  <div class="div1">
   <button class="accordion">Button 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
  <p>Button 2 content and information to go here <br><br><a href="">more information</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  <div class="column">

  <div class="div1">
   <button class="accordion">Button 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
  <p>Button 3 content and information to go here <br><br><a href="">more information</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  <div class="column">

  <div class="div1">
   <button class="accordion">Button 4</button>
  <div class="panel">
  <p>Button 4 content and information to go here <br><br><a href="">more information</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox on .row and align to end

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content:center;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.accordion {
  padding: 18px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel p {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>My footer buttons</h2>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">

      <div class="div1">
        <button class="accordion">Button 1</button>
        <div class="panel">
          <p>Button 1 content and information to go here <br><br><a href="">more information</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="column">


      <div class="div1">
        <button class="accordion">Button 2</button>
        <div class="panel">
          <p>Button 2 content and information to go here <br><br><a href="">more information</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="column">

      <div class="div1">
        <button class="accordion">Button 3</button>
        <div class="panel">
          <p>Button 3 content and information to go here <br><br><a href="">more information</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="column">

      <div class="div1">
        <button class="accordion">Button 4</button>
        <div class="panel">
          <p>Button 4 content and information to go here <br><br><a href="">more information</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. Exactly what I wanted.